# Iphone application process flow

Tags: ios4

When we run an app which will be get called first to initiate the app into the running state??

Can anyone explain me the process flow in Xcode.

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in your appdelegate.

Comment: where will the main.m comes into play??? How this appdelegate get   called??

Comment: Very beginning main.m gets called, you will notice there is statement `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass ([AppDelegate class]));` this is where appDelegate of your Xcode project comes into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

along with -

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

We can get more detail information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)